# Allow only integer and decimal number textbow jquery (without regex)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow only numbers in a text input field. so this is what I did :

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".numeric", function (e) {

    if(($(this).attr("class")).indexOf("price") >= 0) {

        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 190 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

            //display error message
            $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(245, 203, 203)");
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #FF0000");    
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Enter only numbers");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added `e.which != 190` to allow decimal numbers but it doesn't work. And event if that works, it'll allow the user to enter somthing like `12.9.32.` which is wrong.

Do you have any idea about this ? Thank you

Comment: just out of curiosity, why not allow regex? and why arent you using a plugin like js validate? its much easier than struggle with keycodes/which vars. also, consider that the entered value may vary when the event is keydown, keypress and keyup

Comment: You can never rely on keycodes, since some codes can differ between different keyboard layouts.

Comment: @Alex and Johan Thank you I didn't know that Keycodes vars.. I think I'll take a look at JS Validate or write a Regex..

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `<input type='number'>` ? it's HTML 5 and autofilters numbers only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the advices on the comments I solved my problem using Regex expression to have a general code independant of the keyboards types, I'm posting this solution in case that could interest or help someone.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".numeric", function (e) {
    if(($(this).attr("class")).indexOf("price") >= 0) {

        var price = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/.test($(this).val() + price) == false) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(245, 203, 203)");
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #FF0000");    
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Enter only numbers");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
            $(this).removeAttr( "placeholder");
        }
    }
});
```

I have used `Keypress` to not allow the user to enter something that doesn't respect my regex. Since using the keypress event the entered character is not written yet we cannot use `$(this).val()` to get the whole input value, using it we'll only get the **old** input value, that's why we should use : `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` to capture the entered char and then concatenate it with the old value of the input `$(this).val() + price`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for exactly what you are describing. It will allow for only one decimal sign (either . or ,)

```
$elm.on('keypress', function(e){
    //Only allow 0-9, '.' and backspace (charCode 0 in Firefox)
    if(e.charCode == 46 || e.charCode == 44){
        var currentContents = $input.val();
        return !(currentContents.indexOf(',') !== -1 || currentContents.indexOf('.') !== -1);
    }
    return (e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) || e.charCode === 0;
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But I've found a better way to do it, you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is strongest way to achieve integer only html textfield (apply the integerOnly class to the input element):

```
var valKeyDown;
var valKeyUp;


function integerOnly(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        var arrIntCodes1 = new Array(96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 8, 9, 116);   // 96 TO 105 - 0 TO 9 (Numpad)
        if (!e.shiftKey) {                          //48 to 57 - 0 to 9 
            arrIntCodes1.push(48);                  //These keys will be allowed only if shift key is NOT pressed
            arrIntCodes1.push(49);                  //Because, with shift key (48 to 57) events will print chars like @,#,$,%,^, etc.
            arrIntCodes1.push(50);
            arrIntCodes1.push(51);
            arrIntCodes1.push(52);
            arrIntCodes1.push(53);
            arrIntCodes1.push(54);
            arrIntCodes1.push(55);
            arrIntCodes1.push(56);
            arrIntCodes1.push(57);
        }
        var arrIntCodes2 = new Array(35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46);
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, arrIntCodes2) != -1) {
            arrIntCodes1.push(e.keyCode);
        }
        if ($.inArray(code, arrIntCodes1) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$('.integerOnly').keydown(function (event) {
    valKeyDown = this.value;
    return integerOnly(event);
});

$('.integerOnly').keyup(function (event) {          //This is to protect if user copy-pastes some character value ,..
    valKeyUp = this.value;                          //In that case, pasted text is replaced with old value,
    if (!new RegExp('^[0-9]*$').test(valKeyUp)) {   //which is stored in 'valKeyDown' at keydown event.
        $(this).val(valKeyDown);                    //It is not possible to check this inside 'integerOnly' function as,
    }                                               //one cannot get the text printed by keydown event 
});                                                 //(that's why, this is checked on keyup)

$('.integerOnly').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {    //if user copy-pastes some character value using mouse
    valKeyUp = this.value;
    if (!new RegExp('^[0-9]*$').test(valKeyUp)) {
        $(this).val(valKeyDown);
    }
});
```